# Programmically enable meta data tags for all EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, metadata

Earlier this year AWS implemented a feature in which you can [retrieve your instance tags via the meta data url](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/01/instance-tags-amazon-ec2-instance-metadata-service/) which is fantastic except you need to turn it on per instance... I have 20+ accounts with hundreds of EC2s in different regions within each account. What's the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't write a script to enumerate the instances and [turn on instance metadata tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html#work-with-tags-in-IMDS)?

Comment: Yeah I don't know how! The docs show you can use AWS CLI, but how do I use it to find all EC2s in all regions and then apply the setting to every single one?... then switch accounts and do it again? Or I supposed I could just run the script 20+ times for each account.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an ansible/bash script that runs something like:

```
---
- name: Get instance_id
  import_role: 
    name: common
    tasks_from: instance_id.yml

- name: Enable IMDS tags
  shell: |
    aws ec2 modify-instance-metadata-options \
    --instance-id {{ instance_id }} \
    --instance-metadata-tags enabled
```